# Is there an easy way to copy a document field value to another new field in the same document for a whole firestore collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection that has the following document

```
{
  id:"ABC"
  ......
}
```

Is there an easy way to copy that value to another field in the same document for the whole collection?

```
{
  id:"ABC"
  ......
  id_copy:"ABC"
}
```

Im trying to avoid a long running read update script since my collection has about 100000+ records.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward and least expensive way of doing this is to query and read each document to get the field and is value, then update the document with the new field and copied value.  There is no way to shortcut this with a single operation.

Comment: Cool, thank you! Just wanted to be sure before i started writing the script.